# usbip on centos 7 x32

Tags: centos, usb, kernel-modules

I'm trying to enable kernel module to support usbip functionality, but unlike the 64 bit version x32 hasn't relevant section in elrepo repository to download and install necessary packages. Are there any working ways to add them?
Some information about my centos system:

```
└$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (AltArch)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (AltArch)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

└$ uname -a
Linux CentOS-79-i686 3.10.0-1160.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686 #1 SMP Mon Oct 26 11:56:29 UTC 2020 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```